# Laravel 5.4 - rename id and password fields

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.4

I have one doubt, I'm new at **Laravel 5.4** and I've been developing an login for an application, the tables ApiUsuarios have the fields usu_id, usu_nick and usu_password.

My surprise comes when I've been able to add a new user, but not to login, and only way that I can solve this was renaming my usu_id > id and the usu_password to password.

Is there any other solution?

Here is my project in github

https://github.com/kevingcfcb88/pokeapi_laravel.git

In the branch development.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Auth in Laravel is looking for those table names.  To change those, you have to change them in the Auth, although I'm not 100% sure where that is... probably in the Illuminate somewhere.  It's no in the AuthController.

Comment: I think that I can modify in the **vendor** although I know that it's not the right way